How to know Mean Absolute Error (MAE) was calculated from test data or not?
I am trying to calculate Mean Absolute Error (MAE) for a variety of types of models by using Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation (LOOCV) in R. In this link, authors showed guide to calculate MAE by using  caret package in R to conduct LOOCV and then calculate MAE.
The link is: https://www.statology.org/leave-one-out-cross-validation-in-r/
The results is
library(caret)

#specify the cross-validation method
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "LOOCV")

#fit a regression model and use LOOCV to evaluate performance
model <- train(y ~ x1 + x2, data = df, method = "lm", trControl = ctrl)

#view summary of LOOCV               
print(model)

Linear Regression 

10 samples
 2 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation 
Summary of sample sizes: 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, ... 
Resampling results:

  RMSE      Rsquared   MAE     
  3.619456  0.6186766  3.146155

Tuning parameter 'intercept' was held constant at a value of TRUE

However, it is not clear that MAE was calculated by using train data or test data (out-of-sample).

The printed output is clear: MAE is derived from cross-validation.

Please see the algorithm description in the docs, where it is explicitly stated that the metrics are calculated on the hold-out samples (i.e. the "test set") for each CV fold (and then they are averaged).

Roland  desertnaut Thank you for your comments. It helps newbie (me) a lot.
